# Steps for adding a new device to a BeagleBone

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, gyroscope, device-tree

I would like to ask for some help on the steps to add a new device to a BeagleBone. I've searched the Internet and the info. I found was quite confusing or contradictory.

I would like to clarify whether the steps I was able to come out with, are the correct steps in order to add a new device to an embedded system.

So, I would like to read from a gyroscope, particularly an [L3GD20H](http://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/l3gd20h.html) and communicate with it using I2C.

I understand that the steps are:

1. Modify the Device Tree in order to:

   1.1 Configure the Pin Multiplexer in order to allow the communication using PINS 19 (I2C2_SCL) and 20 (I2C2_SDA) on Header 9. In order to do that I should generate a .dts file stating that.

   1.2 Define the new device, that is, the Gyro itself, and state which Driver will deal with it. It should be in a .dts file too.
2. Install the device driver. For instance, this one, from the manufacturer: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Linux_Input_drivers
3. (Optional) Use this library from ADAFRUIT in order to avoid having to configure each register. https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_L3GD20

I created a .dts file for the bullet 1. It can be found in the Drive link below. I think it may be wrong, but I would kindly ask if somebody with experience could just check it out or point me to a good resource for this. I found some examples on that, indeed I based the file on some examples extracted from Stackoverflow and slides from FreeElectrons.

I understand that to get this new information (the information in the dts I created) into the dtb that will be loaded by the bootloader I have to include the dts (btw: Is including a dts instead of a dti in another dts file correct? I guess not, right?) in the general dts of the beaglebone (eg: am335x-bone.dts) and then compile it generating the dtb.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zBRRc2-iAdGJ4X6QLwGZL2ZjQsVEJuUG/view?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot!